# Find $\frac{1}{1.2.3.4}+\frac{4}{3.4.5.6}+\frac{9}{5.6.7.8}+\frac{16}{7.8.9.10}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> Prove that
>   $$
> \frac{1}{1.2.3.4}+\frac{4}{3.4.5.6}+\frac{9}{5.6.7.8}+\frac{16}{7.8.9.10}+\dots=\frac{1}{6}\log2-\frac{1}{24}
> $$

**My Attempt**
$$
T_n=\frac{n^2(2n-2)!}{(2n+2)!}=\frac{n^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)}\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[\frac{-2}{n+1}+\frac{3}{2n+1}+\frac{2}{2n-1}\Big]\\
$$
$$
S=\frac{1}{24}\Big[{-2}\big[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots\big]+{3}\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\dots\big]+{2}\big[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[{2}\big[1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots\big]+{3}\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\dots\big]-{2}\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[2\log2+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\dots\Big]=\frac{1}{12}\log 2+\frac{1}{24}\Big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\dots\Big]
$$
I dont think that the last term series converges so I think I'm stuck, and what does it mean? How do I proceed further and evaluate the infinite series ?

Thanx to @Robert Z for the correction.

**Method 1**
$$
S=\frac{1}{24}\Big[-2[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots]+3[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots]+[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots]\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[\color{red}{-2\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]}+2\big[-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\dots\big]+\color{red}{2\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]}+\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]+\big[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[2(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\dots)+2(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots)-1\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}[2\log2-1]\implies\boxed{S=\frac{\log2}{12}-\frac{1}{24}}
$$

**Method 2**
$$
S=\frac{1}{24}\Big[-2[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots]+3[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots]+[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots]\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[-4[\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots]+4[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots]-3\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[4[1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots]+4.\frac{1}{2}-3\Big]=\frac{1}{24}\Big[4[1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots]-1\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}[4\log2-1]\implies\boxed{S=\frac{\log2}{6}-\frac{1}{24}}
$$
Why do I seem to get a different solution in Method 1 ?. And what is so different in methods 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Rewriting the terms $T_n$ turns the sum from an absolutely convergent sum to a conditionally convergent sum whose terms cannot, in general, be rearranged.

Comment: @ConnorHarris I do not have any deep understanding of wht u mentioned. I have edited OP to better explain my doubt, could u pls comment on that ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13888/how-to-sum-frac11-cdot-2-cdot-3-cdot-4-frac43-cdot-4-cdot-5-cdot-6-f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that after the partial fraction decomposition we have that (one of your coefficients is wrong),
$$\frac{1}{24}\left(\frac{-2}{n+1}+\frac{3}{2n+1}+\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{2n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{-1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)+\frac{1}{24}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right).$$
Hence, as $N\to\infty$,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}T_n
&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{-1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
+\frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=3}^{2N+2}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
+\frac{1}{24}\left( 1-\frac{1}{2N+1}\right)\\
&\to\frac{1}{6}\left(\log(2)-1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24}=\frac{\log(2)}{6}-\frac{1}{24}
\end{align}$$
where the last series is telescopic.

P.S. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(n%5E2%2F(2*n%2B2)%2F(2*n%2B1)%2F(2*n)%2F(2*n-1),n%3D1..infinity);) confirms the result. Note that in ss1729's first method 
$$\begin{align}
&S_{2n}=\frac{1}{24}\Big[-2[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}]+3[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{4n+1}]+[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{4n-1}]\Big]\\ &=\frac{1}{24}\Big[\color{red}{-2\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}\big]}+2\big[-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\dots-\frac{1}{2n}\big]+\color{red}{2\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}+\dots+\frac{1}{4n+1}\big]}+2\big[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}+\dots+\frac{1}{4n+1}\big]-1-\frac{2}{4n+1}\Big]
\end{align}$$
and the red part does NOT go to zero!!

Comment: $$
S=\frac{1}{24}\Big[-2[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots]+3[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots]+[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots]\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[\color{red}{-2\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]}+2\big[-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\dots\big]+\color{red}{2\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]}+\big[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]+\big[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots\big]\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[2(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\dots)+2(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots)-1\Big]\\
=\frac{1}{24}[2\log2-1]\implies\boxed{S=\frac{\log2}{12}-\frac{1}{24}}
$$ right?

Comment: @ss1729 No, you are rearraging the terms of a non absolutely convergent series. In that way you change the final sum!! See my edit.

Comment: I have edited OP to include this doubt, could you please elaborate a bit more on why I seem to get a different solution in method 1 ?

Comment: @ss1729 If you are going to rearrange the terms, then you should consider the finite partial sum and then take the limit (like in my edited answer).

Comment: alright. so is this the case with conditionally or non absolutely convergent series only ?

Comment: Yes, if the series is unconditionally convergent you can rearrange the terms of the series.

Comment: $$
S=\frac{1}{24}\Big[-2[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+1}]+3[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}]+[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n-1}]\Big]
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[-4[\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}]+3[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}]+[1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n-1}]\Big]
=\frac{1}{24}\Big[4[1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n-1}]-2+1-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{4}{2n+2}\Big]
=\frac{1}{24}[4\log2-1]
$$

Comment: isn't it the right way to approach ?.

Comment: Yes, this approach is quite similar to my  answer...

Comment: alright. thanx for the help. And could u please send some link whr I can read more about the problem that you mentioned about the conditionally or non absolutely convergent series ?

Comment: @ss1729 See for example:
https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/CMJ/Brown135-138.pdf
http://www.csun.edu/~hcmth017/riemann1/riemann1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As Azif00 did, let us use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{24(2n-1)}+\frac{1}{8(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{12(n+1)}$$ and then consider the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{12}\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{n+1}$$ Now, using harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{2n-1}=\frac{H_{p-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}+\log (2)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{H_{p+\frac{1}{2}}}{2}-1+\log (2)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{n+1}=H_{p+1}-1$$ Combining all the above
$$S_p=\frac{H_{p-\frac{1}{2}}}{48}+\frac{H_{p+\frac{1}{2}}}{16}-\frac{H_{p+1}}{12}-\frac{
   1}{24}+\frac{\log (2)}{6}$$ Now, using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$S_p=\left(\frac{\log (2)}{6}-\frac{1}{24}\right)-\frac{1}{16 p}+\frac{1}{16
   p^2}-\frac{13}{192 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ For a sanity check, $S_{10}=\frac{95219407}{1396755360}\approx 0.0681719$ while the truncated series gives $\frac{\log (2)}{6}-\frac{3031}{64000}\approx 0.0681652$.

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fraction and we get 
$$\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{24(2n-1)}+\frac{1}{8(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{6(2n+2)}$$
Thus
\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)}=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{24(2n-1)}+\frac{1}{8(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{6(2n+2)}\right) \\
=&\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{24(2n-1)}+\frac{1}{8(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{6(2n+2)}\right) 
\end{align}
Use the telescoping series to find the partial sum and continue.

Comment: If that's a telescoping series, you haven't shown it.

Comment: You should mention that $\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{24}$